# Where to find earlier version of DevExpress 10.1 or XtraNavBar.v10.1.dll file?

Tags: devexpress

Extremely looking for Devexpress 10.1 setup file or XtraNavBar.v10.1.dll file for my old project. I looked over most of sites but showing fake results and redirecting on useless websites please suggest.

I have tried using lower and higher versions but not workout.

Comment: The XtraNavBar.v10.1.dll won't do you any good without the corresponding .desiger.dll file used by Visual Studio at design time. As long as you had a valid license during or after the v10 release time, you can still access it via your account as shown by Dmitry.

Comment: Thanks got that and found .dll file from old backup now it's work file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [How to download older versions of DevExpress products](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18618/how-to-download-older-versions-of-devexpress-products) knowledge-base article:

**For registered license holders:**

You can access prior versions via your DevExpress.com account. The following web page contains step-by-step instructions on how to access older builds: [Download a Registered Product](https://www.devexpress.com/support/order/).

**For evaluation purposes:**

Note that DevExpress does not provide outdated versions of its products for evaluation purposes. Trial support for older versions is not provided either. If you plan to use DevExpress products, you either need to install the evaluation version of the latest release or consider purchasing a corresponding product license. If you purchase a license, you will be able to download any version of the corresponding product and support service will be available to you for free.